# I am trying to download "robotframework-OracleLibrary- version 0.0.3-dev0" in Windows using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, python-requests

Got this long error and Can any one help me on this?

```
 > C:\Python36>python -m pip install robotframework-OracleLibrary --user

  Collecting robotframework-OracleLibrary
  Using cached robotframework-OracleLibrary-0.0.3-dev.tar.gz (2.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
   sys.argv[0] = 
  '"'"'C:\\Users\\pp22\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
  senqzew1\\robotframework- 
  OracleLibrary\\setup.py'"'"'; 
  __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pp22\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
  senqzew1\\robotframework-OracleLibrary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
  '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
  (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
  '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
  '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pp22\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
  pip-egg-info-sz_t7m2p'
         cwd: C:\Users\pp22\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
   senqzew1\robotframework-OracleLibrary\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\pp22\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-senqzew1\robotframework- 
  OracleLibrary\setup.py", 
  line 4, in <module>
        execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'OracleLibrary', 'version.py'))
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. `robotframework-OracleLibrary`, the only [version 0.0.3-dev](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-OracleLibrary/0.0.3-dev/) was released in 2014. [The homepage](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-OracleLibrary/) doesn't exist.

The code uses `execfile` that was [a builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#execfile) in Python 2.7 but [was removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=execfile#builtins).

Resume: the package is old abandoned Python2-only. Forget it and move on.